# ios5 on snow leopard crashes but ok on Lion os

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, crash

I need to do un update on an app that is on the appStore, but right now im on holidays very far from my work computer (Lion os xcode 4), so Im using another computer (Snow leopard 10.6.8, xcode 4),

I have exported the svn repo with the source code [which was working fine on ios5 and ios4 on the lion machine],

but now to my horror, the app crashes in ios 5 simulator[no message for the crash in the log]
[image: error]

It works fine on ios4 simulator

so is this related to the different os?

I dont have here my ipad to test so I dont know if it would work on the actual device,

so what can it be?

thanks!

Comment: Do you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: hi thanks, I have some warnings of Semantic Issues, Unused variable and one of Deprecations... but what is very strange to me is that it was working fine in the work computer. What could it be?, thanks

Comment: You should not call deprecated methods. See the documentation and update the code accordingly. Maybe the method you call isn't implemented anymore and you send a message the receiver doesn't respond to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an uncaught exception isn't being logged. Add the following to your main.m:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
void eHandler(NSException *);

void eHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@", exception);
    NSLog(@"%@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
}
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

#ifdef DEBUG
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&eHandler);
#endif

...rest of your main function here...

}
```